# Files exists within documents folder

Tags: iphone, documents

I am looking the way to check if is all files needed exists on documents folder. 
By now I had only one file to check in this document and is working fine with this code :

```
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
 NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"01.mp3"];
 if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
 {
      [progressIndicator setHidden:YES];
      [downloadbutton setHidden:YES];

 }
```

What is the best way to check if multiple files like 01.mp3, 02.mp3, 03.mp3 ... exists on the documents folder

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You need to invalidate if any don't exist in the loop and then setHidden for both if and only if allFilesExist

```
- (BOOL)filesExistInDocuments:(NSArray*)files
{
    BOOL allFilesExist = YES;

    for (NSString *currFile in files)
    {
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                        NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:currFile];
        NSLog(@"path: %@", path);

        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
        {
            NSLog(@"not exists!");
            allFilesExist = NO;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allFilesExist)
    {
        [progressIndicator setHidden:YES];
        [downloadbutton setHidden:YES];
    }

    return allFilesExist;
}
```

Comment: How can i set my list of files to check with this ?

Comment: you can call the method passing an array of files to the method.  the other option is to set an iVar or property and then have the method operate on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try appending some iterator to your file name like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < yourFileCount; i++
{
   NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i.mp3", i];
   NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
   if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
   {
       [progressIndicator setHidden:YES];
       [downloadbutton setHidden:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, is working fine but if i use only 0%i.mp3 , I have mp3 files with diferents name like 01-thefirstsong.mp3 , 02-mysecondsong.mp3 ... 15-mylastsong.mp3 . how I can right that for the stringformat ? Thanks